# OSError when trying to pip install shapely inside docker container

Tags: python, docker-compose, shapely, geos

Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']

using the python:3.5.1 image I am trying to run a container that includes among other things it installs in requirements.txt shapely. When the docker container tries to install shapely I get the above error.

RUN apt-get install libgeos-dev

was something I saw trying to search the issue but that returns unable to locate package libgeos-dev

summary:

expected conditions: including shapely in the requirements.txt file results ins shapely being installed when the docker container is built
actual conditions: An error message is recieved during build  `Could not find library geos_c or load any of its variants ['libgeos_c.so.1', 'libgeos_c.so']`

Steps to reproduce:

use docker-compose to build on

Docker-compose.yml:

```
app:
        build: ${APP_REPO}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.1-onbuild
```

Requirements.txt:

```
shapely
```

(Simplified to attempt to isolate issues.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution from: https://github.com/calendar42/docker-python-geos/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#### Install GEOS ####
# Inspired by: https://hub.docker.com/r/cactusbone/postgres-postgis-sfcgal/~/dockerfile/

ENV GEOS http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2

#TODO make PROCESSOR_COUNT dynamic
#built by docker.io, so reducing to 1. increase to match build server processor count as needed
ENV PROCESSOR_COUNT 1

WORKDIR /install-postgis

WORKDIR /install-postgis/geos
ADD $GEOS /install-postgis/geos.tar.bz2
RUN tar xf /install-postgis/geos.tar.bz2 -C /install-postgis/geos --strip-components=1
RUN ./configure && make -j $PROCESSOR_COUNT && make install
RUN ldconfig
WORKDIR /install-postgis
```

I copied this into my dockerfile before the line

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

and the shapely install worked.

It stalls out doing the build occasionally but the main problem was solved.

Comment: This looks correct, but I think you could also build a wheel for the package and install that.

Comment: Stuff i found about wheel files when I initially looked into the problem suggested they were a windows specific thing, is this not true?

Comment: It is not true at all. They are more common on windows because it's often harder for windows users to compile things (they don't always have the same easy access to a compiler), and pypi only includes windows wheels I believe. You can build and use wheels on linux and osx, but you have to build them for your platform.

Answer (score 7):

For alpine, just run following Docker command:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache \
gcc \
libc-dev \
geos-dev \
&& pip install shapely
```

This will install shapely with all the proper dependencies for geo and C related dependencies for the shapely for alpine

Comment: This didn't work for me with the `python:3-alpine` docker image.

Comment: works with python:3.6-alpine. installing geos-dev resolves the missing dependancy during shapely installation. this is the correct solution

Comment: Not work for `python:10-alpine` but it works fine for `python:7-alpine` thank you 

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for my python application. What worked for me was the following:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster


WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libgeos-dev

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).