# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty

Tags: python, docker, pip

Dockerfile:

```docker
FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --trusted-host mirrors.aliyun.com --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

Error during build:

```bash
  Attempting uninstall: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 65.5.0
    Uninstalling setuptools-65.5.0:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/_distutils_hack/'
```

It seems a permission error while deleting a folder. As root is the default user in Docker, I don't understand why lack of permission.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of your `requirements.txt` file it's not possible to say with certainty but my guess is that you included `setuptools` which is
already in the python standard library. Remove this line and it should work

If this isn't the case, add your `requirements.txt` file contents so that the error is reproducible (`docker build` with an empty file doesn't throw errors)

---

[OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) has a number of root causes but error number 39 states

```
 39: 'Destination address required',
```

*found via*

```py
import os
import errno
from pprint import pprint

pprint( {i:os.strerror(i) for i in sorted(errno.errorcode)})
```

---

A couple of related posts:

- [similar pip install format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287636/installing-pip-packages-in-python-docker-container)
- [use `RUN apk add \` with pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377911/oserror-when-trying-to-pip-install-shapely-inside-docker-container)

Comment: Yes, `setuptools` is included in `requirements.txt` which is exported by `poetry`. `setuptools` is one of the dependencies of `matplotlib`. Thus, even root user cannot uninstall a python standard library? Is there other way than manually removing `setuptools` which seems not elegant.

Comment: I've never seen setuptools in my poetry export. There are a number of [options](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry-plugin-export#available-options) that you can play around with but the command I use is `poetry lock -n && poetry export --without-hashes > requirements.txt`. @YueJIN I checked a couple of my projects and couldn't find an example of poetry export including setuptools -- I would reset your poetry instance starting from just the pyproject.toml file

Comment: If you're already using poetry then an alternative approach is to setup your python dependencies within the image also using poetry --> [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763270/14343465)